# Cannot Render Image using GLK / OpenTK

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios

We are trying to make an app using Xamarin which will have a small animated face in a GLKView on a particular screen. We have looked for solutions for rendering sprites, and the best solution we came up with stems from [this solution here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9743/how-to-create-a-simple-2d-iphone-game-with-opengl-es-2-0-and-glkit-part-1). We are having trouble even drawing a simple image in the GLKView, and the [error in the output](http://pastebin.com/BgW4qbH9) does not really make sense. We are converting this from iOS to Xamarin C# so there are differences between certain calls, but we have tried to keep most pieces in tact.

Here are the parts of the code this is related to:

```
public class Sprite : NSObject
{
    public void Render()
    {
        Effect.Texture2d0.GLName = TextureInfo.Name;
        Effect.Texture2d0.Enabled = true;

        Effect.PrepareToDraw();

        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray((int)GLKVertexAttrib.Position);
        GL.EnableVertexAttribArray((int)GLKVertexAttrib.TexCoord0);

        IntPtr ptr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(Quad));
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(Quad, ptr, false);
        int offset = (int)ptr;

        GL.VertexAttribPointer((uint)GLKVertexAttrib.Position, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)), offset + (int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(TexturedVertex), "geomertryVertex"));
        GL.VertexAttribPointer((uint)GLKVertexAttrib.Position, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)), offset + (int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(TexturedVertex), "textureVertex"));

        GL.DrawArrays(BeginMode.TriangleStrip, 0, 4);

        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(ptr);
    }
}
```

Sprite.Render() is called in this GLKViewController here:

```
public class AnimationViewController : GLKViewController
{
    GLKView animationView;
    EAGLContext context;
    Sprite player;
    GLKBaseEffect effect;

    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        context = new EAGLContext(EAGLRenderingAPI.OpenGLES2);

        if (context == null)
            Console.WriteLine("Failed to create ES context...");

        animationView = new GLKView(new RectangleF(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * 0.05f,
                                          UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height * 0.05f,
                                          UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width * 0.9f,
                                          UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height * 0.75f), context);

        EAGLContext.SetCurrentContext(context);

        animationView.DrawInRect += new EventHandler<GLKViewDrawEventArgs>(animationView_DrawInRect);

        View.AddSubview(animationView);

        effect = new GLKBaseEffect();
        Matrix4 projectionMatrix = Matrix4.CreateOrthographicOffCenter(0, animationView.Frame.Width, 0, animationView.Frame.Height, -1024, 1024);
        effect.Transform.ProjectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
        player = new Sprite(@"Player.png", effect);
    }

    void animationView_DrawInRect(object sender, GLKViewDrawEventArgs e)
    {
        GL.ClearColor(0.98f, 0.98f, 0.98f, 1.0f);
        //GL.Clear((uint)(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit));
        GL.Clear(ClearBufferMask.ColorBufferBit | ClearBufferMask.DepthBufferBit);
        GL.BlendFunc(BlendingFactorSrc.SrcAlpha, BlendingFactorDest.OneMinusSrcAlpha);
        GL.Enable(EnableCap.Blend);

        player.Render();
    }
}
```

Links to whole code files:

- [Sprite Class and related Structs](http://pastebin.com/KFm1h2Az)
- [AnimationViewController Class](http://pastebin.com/RKPsnWXJ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is just a typo in the second call to `VertexAttribPointer`. The second `GLKVertexAttrib.Position` should instead be `GLKVertexAttrib.TexCoord0`:

```
GL.VertexAttribPointer((uint)GLKVertexAttrib.Position, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)), offset + (int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(TexturedVertex), "geomertryVertex"));
GL.VertexAttribPointer((uint)GLKVertexAttrib.TexCoord0, 2, VertexAttribPointerType.Float, false, Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TexturedVertex)), offset + (int)Marshal.OffsetOf(typeof(TexturedVertex), "textureVertex"));
```